# Job title column

Tags: sharepoint-designer, column

Is there a way I can capture the users job title at the time they add an item to a list. I'm able to show the users job title in a column however it will change when their job title changes. I would like it to remain the same so the job title is what it was at the time they added the item to the list.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the technique you use to show the user's job title.

It would help if you could update your question with that detail.

In general, if you want to capture circumstantial data at creation, you may want to use a workflow that fires when an item gets created. Let that workflow discover the data items you want to capture, e.g. the user's job title, and then write that data to a list column that is used to store that data. If the workflow runs only when an item is created, then that's all you need. The data won't be changed if the existing item is updated.

Edit after comment: If you use a people column to show the person's job title, add a text column to the list and then use a workflow that writes the desired property of the people field to the text column when the item is created. That can be done in a SharePoint Designer workflow that kicks off when an item is created.

Comment: I use a people/group column that is set to display 'Title'. I cant seem to store job title in any other type of column. Unfortunately this column acts as a link to the users profile which means it will change when the users details change.

Comment: I've tried using a workflow to copy the job title to a text column. For some reason it appears as the users full name instead of the job title.

Comment: I added a suggestion in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with teylyn. Please use the below link to show you how to do this. It's pretty easy once you get the hang of it. If the information is loaded into the user profile you can call it with a Designer workflow.

http://blog.bonzai-intranet.com/analysthq/2011/04/user-profile-data-in-sharepoint-designer-workflows/

Respond if you have any other questions.